# 2 teamspeak server on 1 domain?

Tags: dns, cross-domain, teamspeak

i have a question, i have a domain ".ga" and i would like to know if you can go about the link "domain.ga" from the browser, it connects to the site (ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 80) and if I place the same link on teamspeak it connects to a server with different ip (yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy: 9987), is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `domain.ga` can either resolve to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx or yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy but not both. The port number is used *after* the IP is resolved.

What you can do is use `subdomain.domain.ga` to point to one IP and `subdomain2.domain.ga` to point to second IP.